# I'm looking for an algorithm for finding the convex hull of a set of 3D points

Tags: c++, collision-detection, convex-hull

I have a set of points defined as the following, for example:

```
    vector<glm::vec3> points =
    { {1, 1, 1}, {1, 6, 1}, {7, 1, 1}, {7, 6, 1}, {3, 3, 1} };
```

I am looking for an algorithm which can take these points as an input and output their convex hull.

I am developing a C++ project for determining collision detection between two convex hulls and so far have everything working when I use arbitrary point clouds. However, I would like to implement proper convex hulls for the final edition

Comment: Please, try [google "convex hull of 3d points c++"](https://www.google.com/search?q=convex+hull+of+3d+points+c%2B%2B).

Comment: ...and a hint for reading: Christer Ericson: Real-Time Collision Detection ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the question and tried some of the different implementations that the google result brings up before, I just don't fully understand how to get them working for my project. I am reading through the RTCD book as well as Computational Geometry by Marc De Berg.